# Partial derivative of a non-defined function. (These are two different questions, not the same one)

Tags: calculus

[image]

Please forgive me, I'm not well-versed in using the symbols yet.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for MathJax.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

For the first one,

$z_u  = z_xx_u + z_yy_u = z_xe^u - z_ye^{-u}$
$z_v = -z_xe^{-v}-z_ye^v$

Now perform $z_u-z_v$

---

For the second one,

$$u=u\bigg(\frac 1x-\frac 1y,\frac1x - \frac1z\bigg)$$ 
Let $p = \frac 1x-\frac 1y,q=\frac1x - \frac1z$

$u_x = u_pp_x + u_qq_x$
$u_y = u_pp_y+u_qq_y$
$u_z = u_pp_z+u_qq_z$